# JS: alert when clicking on a tag

Tags: javascript, events, dom

i want to get alert when a A' tag inside the iframe is clicked , here is my code :

```
<Html>
<Head>
    <Title>change links</Title>
</Head>
<body>
    <iframe id="tab" src="http://www.site.com"></iframe>
    <script type="text/javascript">
          var tags = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
          tags.addEventListener("click", alert(""), false);
    </script>
</body>
</Html>
```

*the iframe isn't the same domain as where the script is running

why is't that working?

Comment: hmmm i didnt ready this correcly, you can't access the links inside the iframe if they are in a different subdomain

Answer (score 3):

Becouse this is considered a Cross-Site request or also called XSS attack. It is strictly `PROHIBITED` to read or modify in any way the content of an iframe on a different domain.

Furthur more frames are deprecated in the new HTML5 standart, so using them is discouraged.